# How to write a simple multicloud program (may be a helloworld program) using python?

Tags: python-3.x, api, aws-lambda, google-cloud-functions, azure-functions

I want to deploy a simple program in all 3 cloud services (aws, azure and gcp) as a serverless function with single code base.

For ex. If i run `print("hello world")` in my local machine, it gives me hello world which is explicit. But if i want to run a helloworld program as a function in any cloud services i have to trigger that using a specific Trigger URL. Here the problem arise each cloud service provider uses diff methodology to invoke the program. Google uses flask framework, azure uses functions framework  and aws uses lambda. How can i gendralise my code to run in all the 3 platforms. Or is there any libraries avalable to handle this issue?

Answer (score 0):

There will be code which is specific to each cloud provider. There is no way around that.

Spring Cloud Functions has an adapter for AWS, Azure and GCP

https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-function/docs/current/reference/html/index.html

So the same code can be run on each.